# Add required to specific field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I added some class to my form for some fields to be required, but it doesn't work.

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Name', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control'], 'required' => 'true'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save'
        ]))
        ->getForm();
```

also, I added this to my form tag

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'validate': 'validate'}}) }}

    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data

Comment: If I set 'validate' in a form_start then it sets all form fields to be required. But I need specific one.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `validate` attribute?

Comment: Yes, and it's the same as with validate.

Comment: Then you have to set `'required' => 'false'` for the remaining fields

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set as required false all the fields which are not required.

like this :

```
->add('field', TextType::class, array(
            'required' => false //that's what you need
        ))
```

that's why symfony sets all fields required true as default.